# SQL update not committed

Tags: mysql, commit

I am having a weird issue but I do not understand what is happening. I amcreated a function to update up to three columns (end_plan_date, balance and server) in a table (user) and 2 inserts in another table.

For some reason, my last update (column server of the user table) is not committed (**$query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET server='$serv' WHERE email='$subemail'");**) unless I give a value for at leat one of the two other values ($subamt or $subday).

Do you know why this query is not updating the user table with the server value I parsed?

function addBalance($subemail, $subamt,$subday,$userid,$serv) {

```
$q = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE email = '$subemail'";

$result = mysql_query($q, $this->connection);

$dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);

$endplan_date=$dbarray['end_plan_date'];

if($subday >0){

    if($endplan_date=="0000-00-00" ){ 

        $endplan_date = date('Y-m-d');

        $new_endplan_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endplan_date . "+".$subday." days"));

    }else{

        $new_endplan_date = date('Y-m-d',strtotime($endplan_date . "+".$subday." days"));

    }

    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET end_plan_date='$new_endplan_date' WHERE email='$subemail'");
    $recdate=gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $q = "INSERT INTO com_gest(recdate,userid,type,recvalue) VALUES ('$recdate','$userid','Plan Date','$subday')";
    mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
if($subamt >0){
    $query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET balance=balance+".$subamt." WHERE email='$subemail'");
    $recdate=gmdate('Y-m-d H:i:s');
    $q = "INSERT INTO com_gest(recdate,userid,type,recvalue) VALUES '$recdate','$userid','Balance','$subamt')";
    mysql_query($q, $this->connection);
}
$query = mysql_query("UPDATE user SET server='$serv' WHERE email='$subemail'");
return 0;
```

}

Comment: What's the question that you'd like answered?

Comment: Hi jerdiggity,I would like to know what I did wrong and why my column server from the user table is not updated if I enter a value only for this one, leaving the two other ones empty

Answer (score 0):

In your code u can't get directly this

```
$endplan_date=$dbarray['end_plan_date'];
```

for fetching this variable u have to use while loop like

```
while($dbarray = mysql_fetch_array($result);) {

   $endplan_date=$dbarray['end_plan_date'];
}
```

Comment: Hi Jivani, Thanks for this does not fix my issue. I still have to either enter $subamt or $subday to be able to update $server.

Answer (score 0):

There was an issue when calling this function.